# Pyplot errorbar keeps connecting my points with lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am having trouble getting these lines between my data points to go away! It seems to be whenever I try to add error bars it does this. If you look at the graphs, the first is without the errorbar line, and the second is with it. Is this a usual side effect of pyplot errorbar? Does anyone know why it does this, or how to make it go away?

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label = 'blah')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = None, xerr = x_err) 
plt.plot(x, f) #this is a line of best fit
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set the line style (`ls`) to `'none'` (**caution:** `ls=None` does not work):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
yerr = np.random.random(10)
xerr = np.random.random(10)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(x, y, label = 'blah')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = None, xerr = xerr) 

plt.subplot(122)
plt.scatter(x, y, label = 'blah')
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = None, xerr = xerr, ls='none')
```

[image]

Comment: It is important to highlight ls='none'. I think many people use None in Python.

Comment: @emma, I have rejected your suggested edit, which was summarized as: _"Changed the code to use ls='none' instead of ls=None which just does not work"_. You didn't do that; my example code already used `ls='none'`, and you only changed `yerr=None` to `yerr='none'`...