# plot actual and predicted truth value as a vertical line over a time for comparison

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to visualize the actual and predicted value where the truth value is True for both over time. I want the output to look like the image below:

[image: 1]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use errorbars without lines. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020492/2681662. Notice in this example the answer shows how to plot errors on x axis. What you need to change the error bar to y axis.

Comment: @MSH, thank you for the lead, I will check it out right away.